# Hybris back office customization

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Need to   customize hybris back office advance search filtered with  product classification.
Try to include features from product data, but its not  displaying in backoffice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that will help you: in BackOffice (https://localhost:9002/backoffice)

1. Click F4.
2. Click the SAP Commerce icon in the right upper corner.
3. Select Reset Everything option from menu.
4. Go back to the standard view by pressing F4.

see : https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/21699fe172bc4ed38e7e3a57efa53eb8.html